# use array to create dynamic image slider

Tags: javascript, css

currently i am trying to create an image slider.a two element array is used to store the image sources.don't know whats wrong ,my slider is not working though everything looks fine .pls help me out .thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myimage {
    opacity=0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function lol(){
    var check=true;
    var i=0;
    var array=["car1.jpg","car2.jpg"];
    var imgs=doucment.getElementById("myimage");
    setInterval(function(){
        if(check){
            imgs.style.opacity=1;
            imgs.style.transition="opacity 2s ease-in-out";
            imgs.src=array[i];
            i++;
            if(i=2){i=0;}
            check=false;
        }else{
            imgs.style.opacity=0;
            imgs.style.transition="opacity 2s ease-in-out";
            check=true;
        }
    },2000);
}    
window.onload=lol;
</script>
<img src="" id="myimage">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo in your example only or is this in your actual code: `doucment.getElementById("myimage");`?

Comment: In CSS you must use `#myimage {opacity:0;}` instead of `#myimage {opacity=0;}`

Comment: thanks.it is fixed now.actually it was on my own code .i am using notepad ,it does not show any error. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few problems in the code you posted:

`doucment.getElementById("myimage");` should be `document.getElementById("myimage");`

---

The css :

```
#myimage {
    opacity=0;
}
```

should be

```
#myimage {
    opacity:0;
}
```

---

```
if(i=2){i=0;}
```

should be:

```
if(i === 2){i=0;}
```

Note: if you press <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser, the console will open and it will show you the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct 2 steps:

1. correct typo **doucment** to **document**

   *var imgs=document.getElementById("myimage");*
2. Add your JS code to the bottom of page

**Suggestion for better slider:** since you are looking for slider hence you should always compare with array length as shown below:

**if(i==array.length){i=0;}**

***Now here is the complete working code.***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myimage {
opacity=0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function lol(){
var check=true;
var i=0;
var array=["car1.jpg","car2.jpg"];
var imgs=document.getElementById("myimage");
setInterval(function(){
if(check){
imgs.style.opacity=1;
imgs.style.transition="opacity 2s ease-in-out";
imgs.src=array[i];
i++;
if(i==array.length){i=0;}
check=false;
}else{
imgs.style.opacity=0;
imgs.style.transition="opacity 2s ease-in-out";
check=true;
}
},2000);
}    
window.onload=lol;
</script>
<img src="" id="myimage">
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers, 
Ashok